# RabbitConnectionFactory maven dependency

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

which dependencies that I need in order to use RabbitConnectionFactory? I have the below pom, but RabbitConnectionFactory cannot be resolved:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>test.rabbit</groupId>
<artifactId>connector</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My repo is here:
https://github.com/pkid/rabbitconnectionfac

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such class `RabbitConnectionFactory`.

Where are you seeing an error?

With `spring-rabbit`, you would generally use its `CachingConnetionFactory`. It uses an underlying `ConnectionFactory` from the amqp-client library, which is a transitive dependency.

`spring-cloud-service-connector`, in `RabbitConnectionFactoryCreator` creates instances of these objects.